# Invalid expression term 'string' in c#

Tags: c#

```
public delegate void FileDelegate(List<string> str);
public event FileDelegate FilesCompleted;

void upload_Status(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload fu = sender as FileUpload;
    if (fu.Status == FileUploadStatus.Complete)
    {
        if (uploading)
            UploadFiles();
        if (FilesCompleted != null)
        {
            if (files.Count == files.Count(q => q.Status == FileUploadStatus.Complete))     
                FilesCompleted(files.ToList(string));
        }
    }
}
```

When I build the program, I got below Error message:

> FilesCompleted(files.ToList(string)); 
>   "Invalid expression term 'string'"

Comment: In this case, you are using a `Type` name as variable to pass to a method. string isn't a variable, it's a Type. ToList() method doesn't need any parameters.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help on formatting, and use the preview to make sure that you don't make a post until it actually looks readable. Now, what did you *expect* that use of `string` to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you simply change

```
FilesCompleted(files.ToList(string));
```

to

```
FilesCompleted(files.ToList());
```

it should compile.

`string` is a reserved keyword so cannot be used as a variable. Additionally, `ToList` does not take this as an argument.

If you are trying to cast to string, you can use:

```
file.Cast<string>().ToList()
```

Comment: i change my code and compile i got compilation errors ..                            "Delegate 'DC.FileUpload.FileDelegate' has some invalid arguments"  and "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List
<DC.FileUpload.FileUpload>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'"

Comment: public delegate void FileDelegate(List string> str); is wrong.. it should be public delegate void FileDelegate(List<string> str);

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong :

`FilesCompleted(files.ToList(string))`

Correction :

`FilesCompleted(files.ToList())`

Also following is a typo ,

```
public delegate void FileDelegate(List string> str);
```

Should be

```
public delegate void FileDelegate(List<string> str);
```